# Cannot use Socket.io 2.0.3

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io, webrtc

In the case of developing an videochat app I try to use socket.io. To introduce myself to that library I followed differents tutorials, badly I always have the same problem.

Each time I try to call the library like:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

I have a syntax issue like :

```
Projects/2017_07_24_firstSocketApp/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:140
    this._ultron.on('data', (data) => {
                                 ^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/sandale/Documents/Projects/2017_07_24_firstSocketApp/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/index.js:9:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:430:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:448:10)
C02RN10GG8WN:2017_07_24_firstSocketApp $
```

So I decide to use the previous version like socket.io 1.7.3 which works like a charm. I just want to know if it's a common issue or not, and if someone know a way to solve it.

Thanks by advance

Here my code for that example :
index.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

 io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
 });

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Looks like you're using an old version of Node.js. What does `node --version` return?

Comment: Wow I was totally outdated. I update my version from 3.3.1 to 6.11.1. Work a lot better now thanks !!

Comment: @robertklep - Please write an answer so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrow functions (`(data) => { ... }`) are only supported in (relatively) new versions of Node.js (since v4.5), so it looks like you're using a version of Node.js that's too old.